# C++ saving a text file in an array

Tags: c++

So, I came up wit the following code to open a text file and save it in and use an array to print out all the text. My question is, how can I access a specific word or text in the file. If I am not mistaken there should be a for loop involved in this, but I am not quite sure how to go about doing it.

```
int main() {
    ifstream dictionaryFile;
    dictionaryFile.open("dictionary.txt");
    char output[100];
    //char wordsFromDictionary[40437][22];

    int i=0;
    if(dictionaryFile.is_open()){
        while(!dictionaryFile.eof()){
            dictionaryFile >> output;
            cout<<output<<endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should a `for` loop be involved?

Comment: right now the code just displays everything from the text file. So shouldn't I be using a for loop to pick out the nth element?

Comment: A `for` loop is no more efficient than a `while` loop. You can use `strcmp` with an `if` statement.

Comment: what am  i comparing?

Comment: You want to check for the specific word, no?

Comment: Eventually, the user will be entering a word, and I will be checking if that word exists in the file. So I can just strcmp the user input and the text file array?

Comment: Yeah. That should work fine.

Comment: its c++, use std::string, not char* and strcmp. Load the file into a std::set if you want to know if word x is in it

Answer (score 0):

As you have a char array

```
char output[100];
```

there is no distinction between words in this data structure. File was simply read character by character and stored in the array.

A simple implementation of separation into words (using loops as you requested, with minimal changes to your code), assuming words are separated by a delimiter would be

```
char wordsFromDictionary[40437][22];
char delimiter=...
int i=0;
int j=0
char c;
if(dictionaryFile.is_open()){
    while(!dictionaryFile.eof()){
        c=dictionaryFile.get();
        if(c==delimiter){
          i++;
          j=0;
        }
        else if(j<22) {
          wordsFromDictionary[i][j]=c;
          j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this simply cuts, shortens the words that are longer than 22 chars.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read in some strings, the obvious choice would be to use `std::string`s to do the job. If you want an array of them, store them in an `std::vector`:

```
ifstream d("dictionary.txt");

std::vector<std::string> words{std::istream_iterator<std::string>(d), {}};
```

This reads all the words into the vector. If they're already sorted, you can then (for example) use `std::binary_search` to find whether a word is in the vector or not.